# Pandas dataframe groupby into list, with list in cell data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Consider this input df

```
my_input_df = pd.DataFrame({
'export_services': [[1],[2,4,5],[4,6], [2,4,5],[1]], 
'seaport':['china','africa','europe', 'mexico','europe'], 
'price_of_fish':['100','200','250','125','75']})
```

How to group on a column which contains lists and combine the other columns into a list?

```
my_output_df = pd.DataFrame({
'export_services': [[1],[2,4,5],[4,6]], 
'seaport':[['china','europe'],['africa','mexico'],'europe'], 
'price_of_fish':[['100','75'],'200',['250','125']]})
```

I have tried with

```
my_input_df.groupby('export_services').apply(list)
```

which gives

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Any ideas?

Notes: It's OK if all the grouped rows in my_output_df are lists, even for a single entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, convert to **`tuple`**, which can be hashed:

```
df.export_services = df.export_services.apply(tuple)
```

**`groupby`** with **`agg`**

```
df.groupby('export_services').agg(list).reset_index()

  export_services           seaport price_of_fish
0            (1,)   [china, europe]     [100, 75]
1       (2, 4, 5)  [africa, mexico]    [200, 125]
2          (4, 6)          [europe]         [250]
```

Comment: When I do the apply(tuple) PyCharm can no longer display the df.  I can check the df values and the tuple was applied to the column.  Next for the df.groupby I get this message IndexError: tuple index out of range.  Edit: I only get this IndexError on my actual data, not on the example data.  On the example data columns seaport and price_of_fish are NaN.

Comment: Do you have any values in your `export_services` column that *aren't* lists?

Comment: Thanks for replying.  I checked the export_services column in my data, it is all lists, and futhermore it all converts to tuples.

Comment: That's strange.  Running this on your example data I get the output in my answer.  I'm not sure why you would get `NaN`

Comment: I'm on Python 2.7, you on 3.x?

Comment: Yes, 3.6.5, Pandas 0.23.0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173852/discussion-between-joylove-and-user3483203).

Comment: This was a pandas version issue. pd.__version__ was 0.21.0 and 0.23 solved it. Thank you.